# Drawing a graph with colored nodes

Tags: python-3.x, drawing

I wrote a short code that works (see below), but the uncolored and the colored graphs don't have the same layout.

```
G=[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1] # Define the graph. Upper right half-triangle of the adjacency matrix)
#-----------
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

l=len(G)
import math
nNodes=round(1/2 +math.sqrt(2*l+1/2))

adjMatrix=np.zeros((nNodes, nNodes))
ij=0
for i in range(nNodes):
    for j in range(i+1,nNodes):
      adjMatrix[i][j]=G[ij]
      ij=ij+1
    
# Create a graph from the adjacency matrix and draw
Gdraw = nx.from_numpy_matrix(adjMatrix)

# Draw the graph
nx.draw_networkx(Gdraw, with_labels=True, node_color='lightgrey', )
plt.show()

# Draw the colored graph
Color=random.sample(range(nNodes), nNodes)
print(Color)    
nx.draw_networkx(Gdraw, with_labels=True, node_color=Color)
plt.show()
```

It would be better if both drawings (uncolored and colored) had the same layout.

Comment: i get this error `AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'from_numpy_matrix'` and discover this:  The `from_numpy_matrix` function was removed from NetworkX in version 3.0. If you are using a version of NetworkX older than 3.0, you can use the `from_numpy_array()` function instead.

Comment: interestingly, even if you change `Color` to `'lightgrey'` it still draws two different graphs. So its not the colour that is the issue.

Comment: Even without any explicit color. If you draw three times, the three graphs are different ...

Comment: correct.   i ran the code many times and each time there was a different graph pair.  In wasnt ever there case that `graph 1` was similar to `graph 1` and `graph 2` similar to `graph 2`. every graph appears to be randomly constructed...  it would be worth looking into the docs for this.

Comment: the comprehensive reference is here:   https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/index.html

Comment: As a workaround I finally used the pos parameter, set to nx.circular_layout(Gdraw)

Comment: i found that quite a few of the templates from the website did it really well and you could incorporate colour too.  I provided one (simple) example in the answer.  Glad you achieved it...  it bothered me too !

Answer (score 0):

I see that you can **explicitly set positions** like this:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1, 2)
G.add_edge(1, 3)
G.add_edge(1, 5)
G.add_edge(2, 3)
G.add_edge(3, 4)
G.add_edge(4, 5)

# explicitly set positions
pos = {1: (0, 0), 2: (-1, 0.3), 3: (2, 0.17), 4: (4, 0.255), 5: (5, 0.03)}

options = {
    "font_size": 6,
    "node_size": 300,
    "node_color": "white",
    "edgecolors": "black",
    "linewidths": 1,
    "width": 1,
}

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, **options)

# Set margins for the axes so that nodes aren't clipped
ax = plt.gca()
ax.margins(0.20)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

which produces this (consistently):

[image]

You could work your code and data into the above format to force the positions of the nodes and edges.